# beginner error handling to return boolean

Tags: python, algorithm, error-handling

these are my error handling instructions:

Write a function that takes a function f as its first parameter and a positive integer x as its second parameter. When given these two parameters, no_errors should then apply the function f on every integer from 0 up to and including x. If this series of applications runs just fine (no errors occur) then no_errors should return True. If instead at some point applying f causes an error, then no_errors should return False.

I realize this should be fairly simple but as a new coder I'm struggling to see what is wrong with my code. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
def no_errors(f,x): 
    try:
        for i in range(0, x+1):
            f(i)
            print(f(i))
            return True

    except:
        return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `return True` to occur AFTER the loop has finished, so do not indent as far:

```
def no_errors(f, x):
    try:
        for i in range(0, x+1):
            f(i)
            print(f(i))
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

A working example:

```
def foo(x):
    return x * x

print no_errors(foo, 10)

0
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
True
```

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer if it met expectations @boobooface

Comment: i will once stack overflow lets me in exactly 2 minutes!